# CAS 4.0.0 REST API SETUP: Logging Error

Tags: java, cas, restlet

While following the instructions to enable the REST API on CAS @ http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/protocol/REST-Protocol.html, Upon deployment of my maven overlay I try to POST to

```
/cas/v1/tickets
```

and I get a

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

and a log filled with

```
WARNING: Exception or error caught in server resource
Internal Server Error (500) - The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:517)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:552)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.post(ServerResource.java:1185)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:437)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:350)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:951)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:246)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:211)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:84)
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:381)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.ext.spring.RestletFrameworkServlet.doService(RestletFrameworkServlet.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.jasig.cas.integration.restlet.TicketResource.logFormRequest(TicketResource.java:132)
    at org.jasig.cas.integration.restlet.TicketResource.obtainCredentials(TicketResource.java:112)
    at org.jasig.cas.integration.restlet.TicketResource.acceptRepresentation(TicketResource.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:503)
    ... 54 more
```

I checked the code @ https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-integration-restlet/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/integration/restlet/TicketResource.java and it looks like

```
    /**
 * Log the form request.
 *
 * @param form the form
 */
private void logFormRequest(final Form form) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        final Set<String> pairs = new HashSet<String>();
        for (final String name : form.getNames()) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(name);
            builder.append(": ");
            if (!"password".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                builder.append(form.getValues(name));
            } else {
                builder.append("*****");
            }
            pairs.add(builder.toString());
        }
        LOGGER.debug(StringUtils.join(pairs, ", "));
    }
}
```

anyone with any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven brought in commons-lang-2.5.jar and commons-lang-2.1.jar. 2.1 does not include the method signature provided by the Restlet framework. I removed the version 2.1 jar and the conflict was resolved. The maven overlay template for CAS 4.0 I am using pulled it in. I did tell it to automatically resolve dependencies so ultimately my fault.

If you are wondering I removed:

```
overlays/org.jasig.cas.cas-server-webapp-4.0.0/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar
```